# Conditionless code when working with a time bound cached map

Tags: java, object-oriented-design

I have this piece of code, and I've been racking my brain trying to think of a way in which I could factor out the if statements, mostly as practice to write code that is less conditional and more Object Oriented.

```
String downloadPamphlet(String pamphletUrl) {
    if (cache.containsKey(pamphletUrl)) {
        Instant cachedAt = cacheExpiration.get(pamphletUrl);
        boolean isFresh = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(cachedAt, Instant.now()) < 60;
        if (isFresh) {
            return cache.get(pamphletUrl);
        }
    }

    String pamphlet = downloadRaw(pamphletUrl);

    cacheExpiration.put(pamphletUrl, Instant.now());
    cache.put(pamphletUrl, pamphlet);

    return pamphlet;
}
```

In short, it's job is to return a string version of a PDF file. It should cache the file for 60 minutes or download it from cloud storage if not cached/expired.

This is as close as I've come:

```
private final Map<String, Loader> cache;

String downloadPamphlet(String pamphletUrl) {
    Loader loader = cache.getOrDefault(pamphletUrl, new Loader(pamphletUrl, 60));
    cache.putIfAbsent(pamphletUrl, loader);
    loader.refresh();
    return loader.value();
}

class Loader {
    private final String pamphletUrl;
    private final int timeToLive;
    private String value;
    private Instant cachedAt;

    public Loader(String pamphletUrl, int timeToLive) {
        this.pamphletUrl = pamphletUrl;
        this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        boolean isFresh = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(cachedAt, Instant.now()) < timeToLive;
        if (!isFresh) {
            download();
        }
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    private void download() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Blob blob = storageApiClient.get(BlobId.of("hsy-pamphlets", pamphletUrl));
        blob.downloadTo(byteStream);

        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        value = encoder.encodeAsString(byteStream.toByteArray());
        cachedAt = Instant.now();
    }
}
```

And you could put the time to live in a map as well so you can configure that per URL that you're downloading etc. But I still have the if inside to check if it should re-download or not. Now you could extract that to some sort of RefreshCondition class to encapsulate that logic but I think you're still left with the if, like:

```
if (refreshCondition.check())
```

Which makes the condition more flexible in that it can be anything that turns into a boolean and it is injectable. But is there some way to remove that if as well, and replace it with some object behaviour?

Here is another version that "hides" the if by using Stream.filter:

```
String downloadPamphlet(String pamphletUrl) {
    cache = cache
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> {
                Instant cachedAt = entry.getValue().getLeft();
                return ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(cachedAt, Instant.now()) < 60;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    Pair<Instant, String> pamphlet = cache.computeIfAbsent(pamphletUrl, (url) -> {
        String raw = downloadRaw(url);
        return Pair.of(Instant.now(), raw);
    });

    return pamphlet.getRight();
}
```

Same here, you could store a Condition class instead of the Instant and encapsulate the generation of the boolean, but you still rely on .filter() to do the "if" for you.

Comment: What you want to do *requires* these checks for certain conditions, there's just no way around that. You can hide them away (e.g. in a class Cache that clears expired entries automatically, and then use computeIfAbsent), but they'll be there anyways. And anyone reading the code will have to keep them in mind, no matter whether you hide them behind an abstraction or not.

Comment: That was my feeling as well, I also tried the "remove expired keys, computeIfAbsent" approach but still had to have the if for the expiration check. Couldn't figure out a way to turn that into some lookup. I tried one version where I had a Map<Pair<String, Boolean>, Function> kind of thing, where if I could match the Pair<"Url1", true> I would call the function that either read the value from another map, or that downloaded the file, put it into the map and returned the value. But still needed the if to decide if it was expired or not based on the time it was last fetched.

Comment: It's a bit like declarative code isn't it? At some point all declarative code has to turn into imperative code.

Comment: Code without conditionals use largely useless. I mean sure, you can compute stuff like math expressions, but even easy stuff like fibonacci requires conditions (either loop bounds when you do it iteratively, or checks when the recursion has to end). Conditionals ain't against OOP. That being said, `computeIfAbsent` is usually a good approach when doing caching. And you can use `java.util.Collection.removeIf` to prune the entry set to discard outdated entries.

Comment: Good insights, I'm still trying to poke and prod at the idea of using less conditionals but I fully agree that they're by no means evil when used in the right way, it's usually bad code around them that makes them "bad"!

Comment: Didn't know conditionals made code less OO.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are concerned about object-orientation, I would like to propose to solve the problem in an object-oriented way, by making `Cache<K, V>` a proper class in your business domain.

Interacting with a cache is straight-forward, you only need a handful of methods:

- `V get(K key, Supplier<V> supplier)` - to get the value (of type V) associated with the key (of type K). The supplier is given to acquire the value if it isn't already present, but not called if the value is already cached.
- `void evict(K key)` - to evict a cached item from the cache
- `void clear()` - to completely clear the cache
- (optional, depending on your needs) `void prune()` - to manually trigger pruning of out-dated entries. Usually this shouldn't be needed (as a *public* function, it should be used internally).

From the perspective of the client, interacting with such a cache is rather straight-forward:

```java
String downloadPamphlet(String pamphletUrl) {
   return cache.get(pamphletUrl, () -> downloadRaw(pamphletUrl);
}
```

It would also be possible to supply a `Function<K, V>` vis the constructor of the cache, and not to pass a supplier on the `get` method, but instead use the function to map the key to the value, if its not already cached.

All conditionals thus become internal to the cache itself, and the caller isn't concerned anymore with *inspecting* the cache and deciding what to do. They'll always get a proper value out of the cache - either the value is present, and they get the cached value, or the value isn't present and they'll get a fresh one. But that is no longer the responsibility of the caller.

As far as internal handling goes, I can easily imagine it as this (using a record for brevity, you can replace this with a normal class if needed):

```java
class Cache<K, V> {
    record CachedValue<V> (V value, Instant expires) {
        public boolean isExpired() {
            return expires.isBefore(Instant.now());
        }
    }

    HashMap<K, CachedValue<V>> cache = new HashMap<>();

    int ttl;

    public Cache (int timeToLive) {
       this.ttl = timeToLive;
    }

    void prune () {
        cache.values().removeIf(CachedValue::isExpired);
    }

    V get (K key, Supplier<V> value) {
        prune();
        return cache
            .computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new CachedValue(supplier.get(),
                Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofSeconds(ttl))))
            .value();
    }

    void evict (K key) {
        cache.remove(key);
    }

    void clear () {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

This code doesn't involve any explicit conditionals, but to implicit ones -- `computeIfAbsent` and `removeIf`. Both convey *intent* quite clearly.

Similarly, the interface of the `Cache` class clearly conveys *intent*, and absolves the caller from inspecting any values from the outside.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really an object-oriented problem, so it doesn't benefit that much from an object-oriented solution. In the solution that you've chosen, it is also surprising that you represented `Loader` as a class but not your `Cache` concept. Though the idea of having cache entries refresh *themselves* is interesting.

What I somewhat dislike here is the mixing of the responsibilities “maintain cache” and “download fresh file”. In both variants, the cache handling logic *depends* on the downloading logic. I would suggest to invert this dependency.

In the past, I've written cache management code like this:

```java
class Cache<T> {
  private static class Entry<T> { T value; Instant timestamp; };

  private Clock clock = ...;
  private HashMap<String, Entry<T>> cache = ...;

  public T cached(String key, Instant earliestAcceptableTimestamp, Supplier<T> producer) {
    Entry<T> entry = cache.putIfAbsent(key, new Entry());

    if (entry.value == null || earliestAcceptableTimestamp.compareTo(entry.timestamp) > 1) {
      Instant now = clock.instant();
      entry.value = producer.get();
      entry.timestamp = now;
    }

    return entry.value;
  }
}
```

Note the use of an explicit clock and using instants for cache expiry, which helps with testability. The timestamp for new entries is set before the producer starts, thus producing a pessimistic estimate. Note also that the cache HashMap is only touched once.

A different but largely equivalent strategy for expiring items would be to tag the items with the instant after which they expire. The difference is just when the 60 minutes are added or subtracted.

Such a cache can now be easily used to get a downloaded value. This application code does not have to involve any explicit branching regarding the cache status.

```java
Cache<String> cache = ...;

String url = ...;
Instant earliestAcceptable = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofMinutes(60));
String file = cache.cached(url, earliestAcceptable, () -> {
  return download(url);
});
```

You could of course introduce an interface that describes various cache expiry strategies, if a simple time-based comparison is not sufficient.